# Infragistics UltraDockManager: Resetting Panes back to original locations/dock states

Tags: infragistics

We have a requirement to allow the user to customize (position/resize) their panes as they see fit.  We also have a requirement that the user be able to reset the panes back to original (First Run) state.  I don't see anything in the ultradockmanager that allows you to reset to original state.  Any advice?

(Using NetAdvantage 12.2 Win CLR4x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure if this could help you, but I put here as an answer.
Let me know if this doesn't resolve your problem.

The UltraDockManager has two methods called `LoadFromXml` and `SaveAsXml` that save and load the Layout of the control.

You could use SaveAsXml at startup of your form saving somewhere the initial layout, and, when required, call the LoadFromXml to reset the layout at the initial state.

So, for example, to save your layout

```
string userDataFolder=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string fileToSave=Path.Combine(userDataFolder, "MyAppDataFolder", "currentLayout.xml");
ultraDockManager1.SaveAsXML(fileToSave);
```

And for resetting the layout

```
string userDataFolder=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string fileToLoad=Path.Combine(userDataFolder, "MyAppDataFolder", "currentLayout.xml");
ultraDockManager1.LoadFromXML(fileToLoad);
```

Of course I suppose you have a folder (MyAppDataFolder) for your application inside the `ApplicationData` folder where you store application-specific data for the current user.

Comment: That seems to have worked perfectly! ... Thanks! I am using click once, so the user data part is kinda built in for me. :)